# ASP.Net Chart X Axis showing misleading date labels

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts, asp.net-charts

I've got a straight forward column chart with 4 series on it, % on the Y and DateTime on the X axis. All is working fine except that the X axis labeling and interval marks are incorrect (well, misleading). The 1st cluster of columns are Januarys data, however the chart positions the cluster directly on top of a Feb label. The interval line (is that the correct name?) isn't helping either as it runs through the cluster of Januarys data making it look like col 1 & 2 are in Jan and col 3 and 4 in Feb. The data being used runs from Jan to July, with Aprils missing (intentional), however the chart makes it look like it runs Feb to Aug with May missing.

[image: Dodgy Chart]

Data
[image: Correct Data]

So my questions is: How can I centre the clusters of columns in their own interval section with the correct month label on the X axis directly below it? I can even live without the interval line as long as the correct month displays below the correct data.

I've tried this chart with Splines, Lines and without any formatting and they all have the same problem. Help. It's Friday and I want to get this fixed so I can go to the pub.

Update: As requested - code behind:

```
        // set Y axix range
        Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.Minimum = 0;
        Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.Maximum = 100;

        // show y line every x%
        Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Interval = 10;

        // Set axis title
        Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Title = "Period";
        Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.Title = "Percentage (%)";

        // set the x axis date format to short month and year
        Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IsLabelAutoFit = false;
        Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "MMM \n yyyy";

        // The legend
        Chart1.Legends.Add("Default");
        Chart1.Legends["Default"].Docking = Docking.Bottom;
        Chart1.Legends["Default"].Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;

        // load the template for the basic styles
        Chart1.Serializer.IsResetWhenLoading = false;
        Chart1.LoadTemplate("SkyBlue.xml");
```

and mark up:

```
<asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"
        Width="600px">
        <Series>
            <asp:Series Name="thing1" XValueMember="Period"
                YValueMembers="thing1">
            </asp:Series>
            <asp:Series ChartArea="ChartArea1" Name="Team" XValueMember="Period"
                YValueMembers="thing2">
            </asp:Series>
            <asp:Series ChartArea="ChartArea1" Name="Systems" XValueMember="Period"
                YValueMembers="thing3">
            </asp:Series>
            <asp:Series ChartArea="ChartArea1" Name="Env" XValueMember="Period"
                YValueMembers="thing4">
            </asp:Series>
        </Series>
        <ChartAreas>
            <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1">
            </asp:ChartArea>
        </ChartAreas>
    </asp:Chart>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server"
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:myConnString %>"
        SelectCommand="mySP"
        SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="1" Name="ID" Type="Int32" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: can you show some code, like how are you binding it to the chart control?

Comment: Yup - just added it now.

Comment: You have both asp.net and winforms listed clearly this is asp.net. I have removed the WinForms tag.

Answer (score 3):

> the chart positions the cluster directly on top of a Feb label.

Not quite! Look at the data and then look closely at the chart. The first row is dated `31 Jan`, and the cerntre of the bar cluster is, correctly, just to the left (ie just before) `Feb`. Similarly, the second cluster - from data dated `28 Feb` is centered just to the left of the `Mar` axis tickmark.

> How can I centre the clusters of columns in their own interval section with the correct month label on the X axis directly below it

Make sure the data you pass to the chart is the data you want plotted. If you want to work in whole months, make your *data* has only *exact* months - if you had data like

```
Date        Thing1  Thing2
01-01-2012   100     200
01-02-2012   200     200
01-03-2012   300     300
```

your chart would be exactly as you want.

The key is to understand that just saying

```
Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "MMM \n yyyy";
```

doesn't change the underlying data away from a 'full' date, it just changes the output format of the axis.

Answer (score 0):

Set the Interval property in the LabelStyle tag to 1 and your issue with labels being skipped will be solved; it will only put the labels your specify.

Chart1->ChartAreas->ChartArea1->AxisX->LabelStyle->Interval

[Source/More details](http://attemptsatprogramming.blogspot.com/2013/05/aspnet-chart-labels-not-showing-up.html)